# Remove only offsetting values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset

I have data with possible duplicates; however, due to the way it is organized and the size of the data it is hard to tell quickly if it is a duplicate record or if it has been reversed.  I'm trying to find a way to delete any record that has been reversed and keep all others, including possible duplicates.  The relevant data resembles as follows:

```
 Date       ID         Amount
1/1/2023   1234        $100.00
1/1/2023   1234        $100.00
1/1/2023   1234        -$100.00
1/3/2023   2345        $150.00
1/5/2023   3456        $200.00
1/6/2023   4444        $300.00
1/6/2023   4444        $300.00
1/6/2023   4444        $300.00
1/6/2023   4444        -$300.00
```

In this scenario I would keep one record for ID 1234, ID 2345, ID 3456, and two records of ID 4444 (including one duplicate).  I'm hitting my head against the wall.  I've tried various iterations of the code below but the lag/lead option doesn't seem to work for me.

```
library(dplyr)

df%>%
    group_by(Date, ID) %>%
    mutate(diff = VALUE + lag(VALUE),
           diff2 = VALUE + lead(VALUE)) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(diff:diff2), funs(coalesce(., 1))) %>%
    filter((diff !=0 & diff2 !=0))  %>%
    select(-diff, -diff2)
```

Comment: Must "reversed" happen on the next line within groups of `Date, ID`?

Comment: No.  In the real data it is not necessarily on the next line.  The main goal is remove offsetting be keep possible duplicates (ie ID 4444)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that a reversal must be consecutive (within a particular group, defined by `Date` and `ID`), I think this works:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(amt = sub("^-", "", Amount)) %>%
  group_by(Date, ID, amt) %>%
  mutate(
    reversed = grepl("^-", Amount) & !grepl("^-", lag(Amount)), 
    reversed = reversed | lead(reversed, default = FALSE)
  ) %>%
  filter(!reversed) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 5 × 5TRUE
#   Date        ID Amount  amt     reversedTRUE
#   <chr>    <int> <chr>   <chr>   <lgl>   TRUE
# 1 1/1/2023  1234 $100.00 $100.00 FALSE   TRUE
# 2 1/3/2023  2345 $150.00 $150.00 FALSE   TRUE
# 3 1/5/2023  3456 $200.00 $200.00 FALSE   TRUE
# 4 1/6/2023  4444 $300.00 $300.00 FALSE   TRUE
# 5 1/6/2023  4444 $300.00 $300.00 FALSE   TRUE
```

Comment: This assumes that the values in `Amount` are always the same for each group. Change the second row to 200 to check.

Comment: yeah, plenty of assumptions. (Related: not using a `group_by` in your answer is as fragile if not more to the order of rows by date/id.)

Comment: I have `group_by` --> ```.by = c(Date, ID)```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr) # Version 1.1.1

df %>% 
  mutate(value = as.numeric(gsub('[$,]', '', Amount))) %>% 
  filter(value != -lag(value, default = 0), value != -lead(value, default = 0), 
         .by = c(Date, ID))
#>       Date   ID  Amount value
#> 1 1/1/2023 1234 $100.00   100
#> 2 1/3/2023 2345 $150.00   150
#> 3 1/5/2023 3456 $200.00   200
#> 4 1/6/2023 4444 $300.00   300
#> 5 1/6/2023 4444 $300.00   300
```

##### Data:

```
read.table(text = "Date       ID          Amount
                   1/1/2023   1234        $100.00
                   1/1/2023   1234        $100.00
                   1/1/2023   1234        -$100.00
                   1/3/2023   2345        $150.00
                   1/5/2023   3456        $200.00
                   1/6/2023   4444        $300.00
                   1/6/2023   4444        $300.00
                   1/6/2023   4444        $300.00
                   1/6/2023   4444        -$300.00", 
            header = T) -> df
```

Comment: With this code I’m running into the same problem I was having.  It removes all but one record even when there is a possible duplicate (like ID 4444).  In that case I should have 2 records

Comment: @coult Can you share a reproducible example? Because on the example dataset it works and keeps 2 rows for ID = 4444, as you see in the results shown above.